# prevent aspnet core webpack middleware from doing a first-run webpack build

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I'm running into an issue where if I change and save any c# code in a dotnet core Asp.Net application (for example within a controller) while running a "start without debug" session in visual studio, it will run a first-run Webpack build, even if no javascript code is changed:

```
1>Performing first-run Webpack build...
1>Hash: e3e29292b63fc407c658
1>Version: webpack 3.11.0
1>Child
```

This makes it really slow to make changes to dotnet code. However, if I am working on just javascript code (vue files for instance), the Hot Module Replacement works well and it updates very quickly without doing a full webpack build.

I am working on an application which I haven't ported to Webpack 4 yet, but I was wondering if this is something to do with my asp.net configuration.

I am using the following in my startup.cs, before a call to `app.UseStaticFiles();`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{                
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
        HotModuleReplacement = true
    });
}
```

Is there a way to prevent the first-run webpack build if there are no changes to javascript files? It seems like the webpack build should be called by dotnet only if there are changes in javascript files, not in pure c# code.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, if you find something please let me know!